# How to set workflow on survey creation in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, list, sharepoint-2007, workflow, survey

I want to set workflow on survey creation to create list item, like, when I create survey, I want item of list to be created automatically. 
My list contains  title, creation Date, Created By, Survey Link. On survey creation I want to create list item with filled title and Survey link column automatically. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2007, a workflow is tied to a library or a list. You can't tied a workflow to a survey creation statement.

A survey is a list with a diferent content type. Did you consider to build webpart with fields like title, date,... and an action button. Click on the button will create both the entry in the list and the frame survey.